# call javascript object method using partial arguments from outer scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have a getValidators function which returns an object with validator methods:

```
export function getValidators()  {

  return {
    required: (node, value, [mark='', falsy=[undefined, '']]) => {
      const notValid = falsy.includes(value);
      return setNotValid(node, notValid, mark);
    },
    // ... other validator functions ...
  };
};
```

All the validator functions have three arguments: node, value and an array: args

I can run the validator function:

```
let validator = 'required';
let validators = getValidators()
let result = validators[validator](node, value, args);
```

But I like to run the modified validator function below using the arguments node and value from some outer scope:

```
export function getValidators()  {

  return {
    required: ([mark='', falsy=[undefined, '']]) => {
      const notValid = falsy.includes(value);
      return setNotValid(node, notValid, mark);
    },
    // ...
  };
};
```

And like to run it as shown below:

```
// ... node and value args passed in from outer scope ...?
let result = validators[validator](args);
```

**Update:** I cannot use `getValidators(node, value)` because getValidators will be called first to add additional validator functions.

```
let validators = getValidators();
validators[method] = aValidatorFunc;
.....
.....
function runValidators() {
  .....
  // use the updated validators instance to run the validators
  for (let validator of .....) { 
     // node and value will change in this loop as well
     ... 
     let result = validators[validator](args);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? Which part is not working? Where do you have a problem?

Comment: How can I pass in (node, value) from an outer scope?

Comment: why not use the arguments? thats what they are there for. and what exactly do you mean with "an outer scope"

Comment: Yes, this is possible. "*`node` and `value` from some outer scope*" - well, from **which** outer scope? They currently don't exist at all in your modified code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if that is what you mean, but you can pass them in from the outer functions' scope like so:

```
export function getValidators(node, value)  { // Put them in the argument list here
  return {
    required: ([mark='', falsy=[undefined, '']]) => {
      const notValid = falsy.includes(value);
      return setNotValid(node, notValid, mark);
    },
    //...
  };
};
```

```
let validator = 'required';
let validators = getValidators(node, value); // Pass your node and value to the outer function

// Now call it like you wanted to call it:
let result = validators[validator](args);
```

Comment: Yes You are very right. But getValidators has to be called before node an value are available. This first call is used to add dynamic validators.

Comment: well clarify your question then. where do your node and value come from and when do you want to have them where.

Answer (score 0):

Found a kind of solution using bind(this):

```
let validators = getValidators();
validators[method] = aValidatorFunc;
.....
.....
function runValidators() {
  .....
  // use the updated validators instance to run the validators
  for (let validator of .....) { 
     // node and value will change in this loop as well
     ...
     const validatorFunc = validators[validator].bind({node, value})  // bind this
     // or with call with a given this as firtst argument: 
     // const validatorFunc = validators[validator].call({node, value}, args); 

     let result = validatorFunc(args);
  }
  ...
}
```

With bind we cannot use an arrow function, so to use 'this':

```
export function getValidators()  {

  return {
    required: function([mark='', falsy=[undefined, '']]) {  // function
      const notValid = falsy.includes(this.value);
      return setNotValid(this.node, notValid, mark);
    },
    // ...
  };
};
```